# Breaking the recursion in between in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I tried to find a form is valid or not. I have the error object and that will nested in to any level. I tried to loop through using recursion. It is returning the correct response. But when i find an error that form will become invalid, after that not necessary to loop through the remaining object. I am not sure how to break the recursion when i find the form is invalid.
here is my code

```
const errors = {
  "fields": [
    {
      "field": [
        {
          "field1": "THis is required"
        },
        {
          "field2": ""
        },
        {
          "field3": null
        },
        {
          "field4": undefined
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}

function checkIsFormValid() {
  let isFormValid = true;
  function isValidForm(data) {
    if(!isFormValid) {
      return isFormValid;
    }
    Object.keys(data).forEach((el) => {
      if(Array.isArray(data[el])) {
        data[el].map((val,index) => {
            console.log(typeof data[el][index], data[el][index]);
            return isValidForm(data[el][index])
        })
      }else if(typeof data[el] === 'Object') {
        return isValidForm(data[el])
      }else if(typeof data[el] === 'string'){
                if(data[el].trim()) {
            isFormValid = false;
            isValidForm(data, false)
        }
      }
    })
    return isFormValid;
  }
  const formStatus = isValidForm(errors, true);
  console.log('formStatus :', formStatus)
}

checkIsFormValid()
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gowtham25/pg3h2qv6/3/

Here is my js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/gowtham25/pg3h2qv6/3/
I want to break the recursion when i find some error on the object

Comment: It seems your function only reads the rules (in jsfiddle), but does not apply the rules to any data (even though you call it `data`). Also, you keep making a recursive call when the data is of type string, what is the purpose of that? Also, `'Object'` is not a possible outcome of `typeof`. And calling `.map` without using its return value is not how its done. Not to mention that returning a value in a `forEach` loop is useless.

Comment: `typeof data[el] === 'Object'` will never be `true`. Use either `data[el] instanceof Object` or `typeof data[el] === 'object'`.

Comment: @AndrewParks if it is null or undefined that is valid field

Comment: @Gowtham ah ok, I've updated my answer to allow null and undefined as valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `every`, then it will stop as soon as a test fails.

Also note that you can simplify your code, because `Object.values` will work to extract both array elements and object property values.

```js
const errors = {"fields":[
  {"field":[
    {"field1":"THis is required"},
    {"field2":""},
    {"field3":null},
    {}
  ]}
]}


function validate(o) {
  return o === null ||
         o === undefined ||
         typeof o === 'object' && Object.values(o).every(validate) ||
         typeof o === 'string' && o.trim()
}

console.log(validate(errors))
```

Comment: `Object.values({ ...o })` can be used as a fail-safe method for `null` (and `undefined`).

Comment: @InSync Wow, great point, I didn't know that `typeof null === 'object'` (I just checked, and `typeof undefined === 'undefined'`, so that case is not an issue)

Comment: That, or `o instanceof Object` / `o && typeof o === 'object'`. `undefined` is just another nice thing to have since just about anything can be spreaded into an object.

Comment: It is always return false @AndrewParks

Comment: @Gtm if you set field2 to a non-empty string, then it will validate. Have I not understood your criteria? It validates as long as every element within every object or array is a non-empty string, null, or undefined